# Apple ResearchKit cause Missing Info.plist key

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, researchkit

I am doing a project using [ResearchKit](http://researchkit.org) by Apple and my app is using it as a framework. I've already imported it into the same folder of my current project and everything built and runs just fine. To be specific I've added the framework into 3 places.

1. Embedded Binaries
2. Linked Frameworks and Libraries

[image]

Which should work fine as a normal procedure of linking frameworks. I end up getting this email from Apple Developer when I submit the app to Apple and I think that the problem is with ResearchKit info.plist itself. If anyone has the same problem it would be great to share how to solve the problem. My app didn't ask user for NSMotionUsageDescription, NSMicrophoneUsageDescription, NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription, and NSHealthShareUsageDescription. I think that is the work of ResearchKit.

[image]

Thank you for your help in advance! :)

Comment: Here is a discussion on GitHub for more information about addressing this: https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add NSMicrophoneUsageDescription and other keys & values in to your plist file, and add the justification as to why your app would be using them. They won't be shown to the user until your app attempts to use those APIs.

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need microphone access for uploading videos</string>
```

Etc....Do this for each key.

Comment: Thank you. One quick question even though my app didn't ask for user microphone but framework use it I still have to add them? Shouldn't it be included in Framework info.plist? Some suggested that I delete Framework info.plist?

Comment: I wouldn't modify the Framework, and yes, if they are referenced in the Framework you should use those keys.